# Create dictionary from results of DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with results as below.  Sample dataframe shown actual one is much larger.  I want to get a dictionary (or another structure if it will be faster) with the values being all the items that pass the criteria (located in columns headers) and the keys being the dataframe rows.

```
    AAPL    GOOG    MSFT    AMZN    FB
1   NaN      NaN    9.731   NaN     NaN
2   NaN      4.5    NaN     3.486   NaN
3   4.331    NaN    NaN     3.26    5.967
4   NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN    3.61
```

And the results I would want are the following

```
{1:[MSFT], 2:[GOOG,AMZN], 3:[AAPL, AMZN, FB], 4:[FB]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the best in terms of performance, but you could use iterrows:

```
import numpy as np
results = {}
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    results[i] = list(df.columns[~np.isnan(row)])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do boolean indexing on the dataframe columns in a dictionary comprehension.

```
>>> {idx: df.columns[row].tolist() for idx, row in df.notnull().iterrows()}
{1: ['MSFT'], 2: ['GOOG', 'AMZN'], 3: ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'FB'], 4: ['FB']}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the dot product of mask and columns and then use string operations i.e

```
df.notna().dot(df.columns+',').str.strip(',').str.split(',').to_dict()

{1: ['MSFT'], 2: ['GOOG', 'AMZN'], 3: ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'FB'], 4: ['FB']}
```

Comment: Note that .notna() is only available for [pandas 0.21.1 or newer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21.1/whatsnew.html)

Comment: @kitman0804 Yes, you can use `.notnull()`, anyway this answer is going to get older let it be in its newest form and I have already upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
df.stack().reset_index(level=1).groupby(level=0).level_1.apply(list).to_dict()
Out[764]: {1: ['MSFT'], 2: ['GOOG', 'AMZN'], 3: ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'FB'], 4: ['FB']}
```

Comment: Nice, using `stack` to get rid of NaNs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.apply`

```
df.apply(lambda x: list(x.dropna().index), axis=1).to_dict()       #Updated answer
# Or dict(df.apply(lambda x: list(x.index[~x.isnull()]), axis=1))  #Original answer
```

Output:

```
{1: ['MSFT'], 2: ['GOOG', 'AMZN'], 3: ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'FB'], 4: ['FB']}
```